# List all files added in last 24 hours

Tags: php

I recently found this PHP script on another forum - it supposedly puts all files in a specified directory in an array from newest to oldest, then returns the newest file by doing array[0].

Is there any way this script can be applied to get all the files within last 24 hours?

Thanks in advance for any help, here is the code:

```
<?php
$path = "docs/";
// show the most recent file
echo "Most recent file is: ".getNewestFN($path);

// Returns the name of the newest file 
// (My_name YYYY-MM-DD HHMMSS.inf)
function getNewestFN ($path) {
// store all .inf names in array
$p = opendir($path);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($p))) {
if (strstr($file,".inf"))
$list[]=date("YmdHis ", filemtime($path.$file)).$path.$file; 
}
// sort array descending
rsort($list);
// return newest file name
return $list[0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use:**

```
print_r( get_24h_files('docs/') );
```

**Function:**

```
function get_24h_files($dir) {
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    $before_24h = strtotime('-24 hour');
    $files = array();
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isFile() && $fileinfo->getMTime() >= $before_24h) {
            $files[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

p.s. if you need only `.inf` extensions, add `$fileinfo->getExtension() == 'inf'` into the `if` statement.